# How to use delegates with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsurlconnection

I would like to handle the results of a Twitter request by using delegates 
(I can't use the default block-based methods).

This is how I have set up my request:

```
NSArray *twitterAccounts = [self.accountStore 
    accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];
SLRequest *request = [SLRequest 
    requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:
    SLRequestMethodGET URL:url parameters:params];
request.account = twitterAccounts.lastObject;

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[NSURLSession 
    sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:[request 
    preparedURLRequest]];
[dataTask resume];
```

### Question:

How can I specify that I want to handle the response by using delegation? 
Unfortunately, there is no `delegate` property on `NSURLSessionDataTask` and its related classes.

Comment: Would you mind specifying *why* you "*can't use the default block-based methods*"?

Comment: @esqew: I need to chain multiple URL requests sequentially and the response of each request is being used in the next request. I believe using delegation is easier in order to "iterate" over these requests.

Comment: It should work too with block. You can do something "clean" by simply calling the next method in your completion block (and not the whole code). This way you won't see blocks in blocks etc...

Comment: @KIDdAe: My previous set up uses blocks in a recursive manner (I can post the code here if you want). Unfortunately, in my case, recursion leads to a very high memory footprint (>500 MB for 50 URL requests).

Comment: I have posted my code snippet in a new question. Please refer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312904/recursive-blocks-and-a-bad-memory-leak)

Answer (score 2):

To me it's cleaner to embed the blocks so you can see exactly what the flow is, but to each his own.

In this case you can fake delegation by using a block to invoke any method you want.

You could subclass `NSURLSessionDataTask` to add a delegate property and automatically add the right blocks to invoke appropriate delegate methods.  Block proponents have been using the opposite approach for years to turn delegate-based callbacks into block-based callbacks :)